# How can this function's options be used in different places?

Tags: function-construction, options, optional-arguments

I wrote this function to make a `ListPlot` where the points are colored by a third argument.

```
ColorListPlot[triples_, options : OptionsPattern[]] := ListPlot[
  Transpose[{triples[[All, {1, 2}]]}],
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[triples[[All, 3]]]),
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", Quantile[triples[[All, 3]], {0, 1}]}],
  options
]
```

Note that using `OptionsPattern` I have enabled this to accept options and pass them along to `ListPlot`.

Now I'd like to label that legend using `LegendLabel`. If I pass a `LegendLabel` option to `ColorListPlot` it will end up being given to `ListPlot`. How can I modify the function so that the a `LegendLabel` option is passed to `BarLegend` and all other options end up in `ListPlot`?

Comment: Check `FilterRules[rules,Except[patt]]`